# Python - Multiprocessing suddenly getting stuck, although code is correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, multiprocessing, spyder

I´ve spent the last few hours on the multiprocessing tool in python. Last thing I did was to set up a Pool with a few workers to execute a function. Everything was doing fine and multiprocessing was working.

After I switched to another file to implement my multiprocessing insights in my actual project, the code was running, but the `.get()` invocation following the `apply_async(func, args)` never returned anything.

I thought it was due to a false implementation, but turned out to be something else. I went back to the first file where I did my experiments and tried to run this one again. Suddenly also here multiprocessing didn´t work anymore. Apart from trying to implement the multiprocessing in my project I didn´t really do anything else on the code or the environment. The only thing maybe correlated to the problem is that I tried to execute an older version of the `__main__` program in the same environment, leading to an error because the `__main__` file took to newer project files to execute.

Here´s the code I used for the simple experiment:

```
import torch.multiprocessing as mp

import torch
import time

*#thats code from my project*
import data.preprocessor as preprocessor
import eco_neat_t1_cfg as cfg


def f(x):
   return x*x    

if __name__ == "__main__":   
   p = mp.Pool(1)
   j = p.apply_async(f, (5,))
   r = j.get(timeout=10)
   print(r)
```

So nothing to complicated here, it should actually work. 
However, there is no result being returned. I notice the CPU is working according to the number of processes invoked, so I assume it is caught in some kind of loop.

I am running on Win10, with Python running over Anaconda Spyder with the IPython Console.

When I close Spyder and all Python processes, restart and execute it again it works, but only if I am not importing my own code. Once I import the `eco_neat_t1_cfg as cfg`, which is basically only a dataclass with a few other imports, the program wont return anything and gets stuck in the execution.

I am getting a `Reloaded modules: data, data.preprocessor, data.generator` error. This is probably because `cfg` also imports data.preprocessor. The weird thing is, if I now delete **all** imports from the source code, save the file and run it, it will work again, although the imports are not even specified in the code anymore... however, every time I restart Python and Spyder I need to specify the modules again ofc.

Also, the simple code is working after deletion of all imports, but the more complicated I actually want to execute is not, although it was perfectly fine before all this happened. Now I am getting a `PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'neat.genotype.genome.Pickleable_Genome'>: it's not the same object as neat.genotype.genome.Pickleable_Genome` error. As I said, there were no problems with the pickling before. That´s the "more complicated" piece of code I pass to `apply_async`.

```
def create_net(genome):

   net = feedforward.Net("cpu", genome, 1.0)

   inp = torch.ones(2, 5)
   input = torch.FloatTensor(inp).view(1, -1).squeeze()

   res = net(input)
   return res
```

What I did was to delete all **pycache** in my project, also reset Spyder settings and update Anaconda and Spyder. Also I tried to look at every piece of code of the `cfg` file, but even if I delete every line, also no imports, the program will not work. Nothing helps, I really don´t have any idea of what´s the problem and how to solve it. Maybe one of you has an idea.

One more thing to say, if I manually interrupt (CTRL + C) the execution, in the stacktrace I noticed the processes to be waiting.

```
 File "C:/Users/klein/Desktop/bak/test/eco_neat_t1/blabla.py", line 72, in <module>
r = j.get(timeout=10)

 File "C:\Users\klein\Anaconda3\envs\eco_neat\lib\multiprocessi\pool.py", line 651, in get
self.wait(timeout)

 File "C:\Users\klein\Anaconda3\envs\eco_neat\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 648, in wait
self._event.wait(timeout)

 File "C:\Users\klein\Anaconda3\envs\eco_neat\lib\threading.py", line 552, in wait
signaled = self._cond.wait(timeout)
```

Cheers

**SOLUTION**: The bug was my directory structure that somehow led python to fail. I had both of my `__main__` test files running in the `root/tests/eco_neat_t1` directory. I two new files `t1_cfg` and `t1` with the same content in the root directory. Suddenly everthing works fine...weird world